# Segue is not working from static UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a TableViewController with static cells

I tried both creating segue from TableViewController and TableView cell (Not at the same time)

However, in both scenario, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` was not fired

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("select")
    }
```

I also have embedded collectionviewcontroller

```
class EventDetail: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {
```

What may be causing this?

Comment: did you set table view's delegate?

Comment: @TangZijian it is a tableviewcontroller, should i set delegate?

Comment: In storyboard you have to connect delegate and datasource , but in class not neccessaary to write class EventDetail: UITableViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource as your class is itself subclass of UITableViewController

Comment: @Hasya so what should i do in storyboard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your tableview selection must be single selection, if it is "No selection" then didSelectedRowAtIndex would not get called.

[image]

You can download sample code and observe it.

[Sample download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKQzNUUDZlOG1UT0E/view?usp=sharing)

Also check

[image]

Ideally your cellForRowAtIndex should be like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell : CustomCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ID_CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! CustomCell

    cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    cell.lblData.text = "CustomCell....."
    return cell

}
```

**Swift 4 code**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : CustomCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ID_CustomCell", for: indexPath)  as! CustomCell

    cell.selectionStyle =  .none

    cell.lblData.text = "CustomCell....."

    return cell
}
```

Comment: A question, how can i make cells unselectable without breaking segue?

Comment: cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None in cellForRowAtIndex

Comment: How can i make unselectable all static cells ? should i set identifier for all and do this in cellForRowAtIndex ? Normally i don't use cellForRowAtIndex because it is static

Answer (score 1):

call `performseguewithidentifier` from `didselectRow` if you have created segue from tableviewcontroller. like,

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("select")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("your segue identifier", sender: self)
}
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: have set segue identifier fro `attribute inspector` ? and yes then check it is same in method and in attribute inspector

Comment: Yes i set it and checked everything.

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz you said in your post that `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` was not fired, which means "select" is not printed right?

Comment: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is getting call when you select row? and why you make two segue ?? from tableview and from cell?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not fired at all. I didnt make two segues, i said i tried both, not at the same time